SQLite database is empty in when I create jar file with shadowJar
I have a  multimodule JVM (Kotlin) project with room multiplatform database based on SQLite
I'm trying create .jar with ShadowJar gradle plugin
Project configuration:
 - gradle: 8.10
 - kotlin: 2.0.20
 - ksp: 2.0.20-1.0.25
 - shadowJar: 8.3.0

main module build.gradle
tasks.jar {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE

    manifest {
        attributes["Main-Class"] = "main.MainKt"
    }
}

My BD is filled.
But when I create a .jar with a gradle command shadowJar it makes .jar with an empty database.
DB path is:
${System.getProperty("user.dir")}/repository/impl/src/main/kotlin/repository/impl/db/files/history

ksp schemaLocation is in build.gradle
ksp {
    arg("room.schemaLocation", "$projectDir/src/main/kotlin/repository/impl/db/files/history")
}

If I run the app from the IDEA it works well, but when I make a .jar the DB is empty.
Any ideas why it might happen?
